# Returning Elements Doesn't Work - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was creating an `each` function that handles different kind of callbacks such as

- **iterateCollection**  - w/c just returns/print the array or object items
- **returnEvenElements** - w/c returns even elements of an array
- **returnKeyDivisbleBy3** - w/c returns elements of an array that aredivisible by 3
- **returnKeyWithArrayValue** - w/c returns the key or    property of an
  object with an array value.

Here's what I mean:

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var myObject = {
  num1: 1,
  num2: 2,
  num3: [1, 2, 3]
};

function each(collection, callback) {
  if (collection instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0, l = collection.length; i < l; i++) {
      callback(collection[i]);
    };
  } else if (collection instanceof Object) {
    for (var prop in collection) {
      callback(collection[prop]);
    };
  }
}

function returnKeyWithArrayValue(collection, prop) {
  return collection[prop] instanceof Array;
}

function returnKeyDivisbleBy3(collection, prop) {
  return collection[prop] % 3;
}

function returnEvenElements(collection) {
  return (typeof collection === 'number') && !(collection % 2);
}

function iterateCollection(collection) {
  return collection;
}

var output1 = each(myArray, returnEvenElements);
console.log(output1);

var output2 = each(myArray, iterateCollection);
console.log(output2);

var output3 = each(myObject, returnKeyWithArrayValue);
console.log(output3);

var output4 = each(myArray, returnKeyDivisbleBy3);
console.log(output4);
```

But upon passing the context, it doesn't return anything even one of these doesn't work. I used the '`return`' keyword to return the elements but nothign print them on screen or logs them.

Wondering if I am missing something? Please help!

Comment: You need to return the call back output, in the each function

Comment: return callback(collection[i]); tried this but my functions doesnt return anything still.

Comment: @JamesHedegon if you write `return callback(collection[i]);` then it does return something, see this  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w88e1w8/). It probably does not return what you want, but it returns something.

Comment: yeah but how come given those parameters such as returnEvenElements(collection) for each function it doesnt return anything? Can you check those functions?

Comment: What have you tried as far as debugging those functions?  Have you put breakpoints or console.logs?  Just asking people to "check my functions" doesn't fly well.

Comment: iterateCollection will log the cpllection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't setting the callbacks to any value to return.  Set the callbacks into an array and then return that value out of the `each` function.

I slimmed down the code and gave an example fo `returnEvenElements`.  Hope this helps.

I was able to get `[2, 4, 6]` as a result with the code.

```
var myArray=[1,2,3,4,5, 6];

function each(collection, callback){
  const returnArray = [];  // <- create array to capture values
  if(collection instanceof Array) {
    for(var i=0, l=collection.length; i<l; i++){
      if (callback(collection[i])){ // <- check if condition is true
        returnArray.push(collection[i]); // <- set values in array
      } 
    };
  }
  return returnArray; <- return the value
}

function returnEvenElements(collection){
  return (typeof collection === 'number') && !(collection % 2);
}

var output1 = each(myArray, returnEvenElements);
console.log(output1);
```

PS - Try looking into map, filter and reduce.  You can get the even numbers with -

```
const evens = myArray.filter(value => (value % 2 === 0));
```

Comment: can you give me an example for the object?

Comment: example for the returnKeyWithArrayValue